# Need matrix (list of lists) of boolean OBJECTS (for interfacing to tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

deepcopy is being used in the code fragment below to create all elements in the matrix.  When run, the output shows that all "True" elements share one reference (memory location) and all "False" elements  share another location:

```
import copy

DefaultReports =  [ [ copy.deepcopy( False ) for column  in range( 0, 2 ) ]
                                                 for row in range( 0, 3 ) ]

#Some elements of the "matrix" (list of lists) must be set up differently

DefaultReports[ 0 ][ 0 ]  = True
DefaultReports[ 2 ][ 0 ]  = True

# The remaining code shows that all "True" elements share one location while 
# all "False" elements share another location:

print( "Initialized the ", len( DefaultReports ),"x", len( DefaultReports[ 0 ] ) , 
       " table as:" )
for row in range( len( DefaultReports ) ) :
    nextrow = []   
    for column in range( len( DefaultReports[ 0 ] ) ) :
        print( "(", row, ",", column ,  " @ ",        
                    id( DefaultReports[ row ][ column] ),                
                 ") = ", DefaultReports[ row ][ column],
               " ", sep ='', end = '' 
             )  
    print() 

# Initialize matrix used by rest of code (user can change all elements)

UserSelectedReports = DefaultReports 

# printing "UserSelectedReports" gives the same results as "DefaultReports"
```

What am I missing in order to get (in this case 6) individual elements that can be referenced using [row][column] form?  And, bearing in mind that in the real code the row and column indices are supplied as a list of STRINGS, is there a better (=simple) way to get the matrix effect?

ADDED 20140205:

What's not obvious in the example (initialization code) is that the matrix is an array of mutable boolean OBJECTS (to clarify, trivial code has been appended).  The matrix is used inside a class to track the status of an array of Tkinter checkboxes.  There are several instantiations of the class.  Simplified, my problem is that when a checkbox changes state (in ANY instantiation) - ALL checkboxes in ALL instantiations flip state.  Chasing down this bug isolated the problem to this question.
On the GUI this results in, effectively, only two buttons (shared across instantiations!) - grouped into "initially True" and "initially False" groups (that are mutually independent).  The groupings are determined by the initialization code, in the example setting two elements to "True" and four to "False" shows the grouping effect.

Using deepcopy (instead of "False") was intended to force Python to create (and initialize) an array of boolean OBJECTS, not an array of references to True and False.  From what I've read deepcopy should be able to do this (or perhaps True and False are NOT considered to be objects?)

The class works properly when the matrix is implemented as a vector: matrix @(row,column) = vector @((row * row length) + column). I now need a version that handles a list of lists (or other structure that allows [row][column] indexing where the row and column indices are strings).  Adapting the example:

```
# when the shape of the "DefaultReports" matrix is determined by:

CountryList = [ 'Albania', 'Belgium', 'Croatia', 'Denmark' ]    # Row Titles
FruitList   = [ 'Apples',  'Bananas', 'Cherries' ]              # Column Titles

# Want to be able to reference matrix elements as: 

if UserSelectedReports[ 'Belgium' ][ 'Apples' ] :

    # Do something useful
```

The lists are never changed after initialization, perhaps numpy or OrderDict can give me what I want?  (BTW, In ADA all of this can be easily accomplished by using enumerated types.)  Hopefully I do not have to create each boolean object using "PyObject* PyBool_FromLong(long v)" - as per  http://docs.python.org/3.2/c-api/bool.html.

ADDED 20140207

Summarizing, several matrices of boolean OBJECTS are needed, creating them is the problem.  The matrices isolate (interface to) GUI code from the rest of the program (each tracks the status of it's own corresponding matrix of tkinter checkboxes).  Without these matrices tkinter BoolVar/IntVar objects would have to be used throughout the program, complicating the logic and introducing GUI dependencies into non-GUI code - NEVER a good idea since doing so makes it difficult to change GUIs at a later date.

Comment: the id of True is always the same it does not mean the location of it is the same ...

Comment: Why would you want to deepcopy False?? Deepcopy only makes sense if you have sub elements (like lists, objects, etc.).

Comment: Why is it odd that `id(True) == id(True)`?

Answer (score 2):

Booleans are immutable, so there's only one `True` and only one `False`. Deepcopying the one true `False` returns the one true `False`. You don't need independent `False` objects for independent matrix cells; assigning to a matrix cell will point the list element to a different object, rather than overwriting the old object and screwing with everything else that was using the object.

Comment: user2357112 (and @Cilyan):
I've updated the question (start with the summary at the end) to include the root issue and why I need multiple, independent boolean matrix objects.  The problem may be more of a tkinter issue than a boolean matrix issue.  Note that I didn't have any problems when the boolean "matrices" were implemented as a vector (as explained above).

Comment: @user1459519: Can you show the vector-based code? I'm not sure what a vector is even supposed to be in Python; there's no core or NumPy data structure by that name. Also, are you aware that `UserSelectedReports = DefaultReports` makes `UserSelectedReports` and `DefaultReports` refer to the same object instead of creating a copy?